# How to ask for confirmation before delete an item using ng-select (multi select)?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

[image: Ng-select multi]

I need to ask for confirmation before delete an item from select component. I didn't find a prop to the component. So is there a way to override the delete function?

Comment: Please add some code from html and ts file for respective task.

Comment: seems there is issue open on github regarding clear all https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1313

Comment: anyway which solution did u come up?

Answer (score -1):

The event is called "(remove)", if we're talking about github.com/ng-select/ng-select, which I'm not sure. There is no possibility to "cancel" the removal of an item however. I just checked the code.

The simplest way to confirm an action by the user in JavaScript and Angular looks like this:

```
let result = confirm('Do you really want to delete this item?');
if (result) {
    // TODO delete the item
}
```

Comment: Have you ever used ng-select? Where should I execute your code? I didn't find any prop function which will be executed before delete

Comment: Wow, thanks for the downvote. I tried to help. Based on your provided information, I thought the problem is the confirmation, not the event. The event is called "(remove)",  if we're talking about https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select, which I'm not sure. There is no possibility to "cancel" the removal of an item however. I just checked the code.